# How can I update mysql2 query to not return undefined for return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mysql2, node-mysql2

I am using nodejs and mysql2.  I am storing all my queries inside a class.  When I console.log the results I am able to view the data correctly, however when I use a return statment to return the data, I am getting undefined.  I believe I need to use promises, but am uncertain how to do so correctly.  Here is what I have currently which is returning undefined,

```
    viewManagerChoices() {
        const sql = `SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ',  last_name) AS manager, id FROM employee WHERE manager_id IS NULL`;
        db.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;
           const managers = rows.map(manager => ({ name: manager.manager, value: manager.id }));
           managers.push({ name: 'None', value: null });
           return managers;
        });
    };
```

This is my attempt at using promises which is returning as `Promise {<pending>}`,

```
viewManagers() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const sql = `SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ',  last_name) AS manager FROM employee WHERE manager_id IS NULL`;
            db.query(sql,
                (error, results) => {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log('error', error);
                        reject(error);
                    }
                    const managers = [];
           for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
               managers.push({ name: results[i].manager, value: i+1 });
           }
           managers.push({ name: "None", value: null });
                    resolve(managers);
                }
            
            )
        })
        
    }
```

My class is called Query and I am calling these methods by doing,

```
const query = new Query();
query.viewManagerChoices();
query.viewManagers();
```

Comment: You can view promise results with `.then()` or `await`. Something like this: `query.viewManagers().then(result => console.log("Done:", result));`.

Comment: I don't to console.log the result.  I want to return the result so I can use it elsewhere.

Comment: Then use await. Create an async function (`async function funcName() {...}`) and inside do `const result = await query.viewManagers();`.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation for `viewManagers` is correct however promises don't make calls synchronous.

Either you need to use `then` callback or await the result in async context.

```js
const query = new Query();
query.viewManagers().then((managers) => {
  // do stuff here
}).catch((error) => console.error(error.message));
```

or

```js
async someFunc() {
  const query = new Query();
  try{
    const managers = await query.viewManagers();
  }catch(error){
    console.error(error.message);
  }
}
```

Once you use promise you cannot just get a returned value without `async/await` or `then` flag. Once it's a promise the flow continues as the original.

For example:

```js
// This is promise too because it has async flag.
// You cannot make it sync if you use promise in it
async myFunc(){ 
  const const query = new Query();
  const managers = await query.viewManagers();

  return managers;
}
// It actually returns Promise<...>

// Now if you want to use myFunc in another function 
// You need to do it the same way again
async anotherFunc(){ 
  const something = await myFunc();

  return something; // Returns promise
}
```

You can read more about promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I want to be able to return the managers.  So if I keep the viewManagers function within the class as it is and create the async function (I am doing this in another file) like this, ``` async function seeManagers() {
    const query = new Query();
    try{
        const managers = await query.viewManagers();
        return managers;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}```  I am still getting Promise { <pending> }

Comment: Yes, anything flagged `async` is a promise. Once promise always promise :) . Wherever you reference that you need to use `then` or `await`. You cant make asynchronous operation sync.

Comment: How do I get it to actually show the data from managers when returning instead of Promise { <pending > }?  To test this I am doing console.log(seeManagers);  I tried it as this too, const query = new Query();
const myManagers = query.viewManagers().then((managers) => {
  return managers;
}).catch((error) => console.error(error.message));

Comment: Updated the answer. I understand what you want but you can't do that. Once the promise is involved it's not sync anymore.